# Deploying Python script daily on Azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, microservices

I have a Python script that pulls some data from an Azure Data Lake cluster, performs some simple compute, then stores it into a SQL Server DB on Azure. The whole shebang runs in about 20 seconds. It needs sqlalchemy, pandas, and some Azure data libraries. I need to run this script daily. We also have a Service Fabric cluster available to use.

What are my best options? I thought of containerizing it with Docker and making it into an http triggered API, but then how do I trigger it 1x per day? I'm not good with Azure or microservices design so this is where I need the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Jobs in App Service. It has two types of Azure Web Jobs for you to choose: **Continuous** and **Trigger.** As I see you need the type Trigger

You could refer to the document **[`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)** for more details.In addition, here shows how to run tasks in WebJobs.

Also, you can use Azure function [`timer-based on python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) which was made generally available in recent months.

Comment: I don't see Web Jobs in Azure Portal - did they deprecate it?